# GWT Serialisation and Appengine Channel Api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, channel-api

I am using Google Appengine's Channel API to send events from server to the client.

The problem is Channel API only sends messages of type java.lang.String
So my classes in the ~.shared package needs to be converted to string before 
I could pass them down to channel!

Since I'm using GWT for the client side I thought it would be good if I could
use a 'free' serialisation provided by GWT.

How could I get GWT-RPC service to serialise my objects on the server side 
and send them to the channel?

I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-channel-api/) but it uses undocumented RPC which has already been changed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Serializing for Channel API means that you will have to send a string representation, as long as the receiving client can marshall that string into a sensible object you're good to go.

Take a look at this question: [Json <-> Java serialization that works with gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683123/json-java-serialization-that-works-with-gwt).

JSON is probably what you want to send and receive when working with the channel API.

Comment: I've been reluctant to use JSON since its another serialisation mechanism to be added.

Comment: I understand, it is however extremely handy and resource effective when working with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I look at the Channel API as a way to send small messages to the client and the client can respond accordingly.  This may be a small message just to "wake up" the client and have it go to the server and retrieve your objects using requestfactory or RPC.