# GWT POJO-JSON Mappers?

Tags: json, serialization, gwt, deserialization, mapper

I was looking to find a GWT POJO-JSON mapper. In responses to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683123/) and by Googling around I found following solutions:

- [GWT Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/OverlayTypes)
- [GWT AutoBean](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideAutoBeans.html)
- [piriti](http://code.google.com/p/piriti/)
- [gwtprojsonserializer](http://code.google.com/p/gwtprojsonserializer/)
- [gwt-jsonizer](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-jsonizer/)

My question is that does any of these (or any other) solutions has significant performance gain/lose or any other considerable advantages or disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoBeans get compiled down to Overlay Types when used in client-side code, so they have all of the advantages, and are much easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

GWT Overlay Types have big performance gain, because GWT compiler can optimize and inline calls to field value to native JS calls. Look at [example of obfuscating of overlay types](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html#example-collections).